# Space pilot with a heart defect and a robot friend transports cargo with a crew

Tags: story-identification, books, space

I read this series at least 10 years ago. The story-line takes place in outer space. The main character is the pilot of a starship/space ship/cruiser. He has a small but dedicated crew. I think early on in the book they hire a female member of the crew. The lead character has a medical condition/heart defect. His longest "friend" is actually a robot he has been with since (I think) childhood. He thinks of the robot as his brother. I believe the main character's dad built the robot and some parts for his son's heart. I don't remember what cargo they transport in the space ship but I believe they are all good guys. The age of the targeted reading audience would be the same age readers who would read *Percy Jackson* & *Ranger’s Apprentice*.